# How to get document count within a partition using sql query in Azure CosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We have Azure CosmosDb database where collection is partitioned based on say "/deviceid". We want to get count of all the documents within a specific partition. We ran this query -

```
    FeedOptions options = new FeedOptions()
    {
        PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("f0e14e52ed2c499e893ac934ae934835"),                    
    };
    IDocumentQuery<dynamic> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery(collectionUri, "Select Value Count(1) From c", options).AsDocumentQuery();
    FeedResponse<dynamic> data = await query.ExecuteNextAsync();
```

This query works but at the cost of high Rus. for 153068 documents we incurred ~10K Rus. Indexing mode is "consistent" and automatic is set to true.

Looking for suggestions on how can we get the count of documents without incurring so many Rus.